# QThread, threaded, rly?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt4

for some time I am fiddly now to get a massive time/cputime drain action running behind a nicly responding UI. Unfortunatly I can't seem to get it running and "I think" the problem is that the slot is not processed in the QThread worker but the GUI thread. The ThreadIDs differ as expected though.

I allready read this http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/threads-qobject.html
and used googel and SO search but nothing that really helped me. Probably its something stubborn I just don't see.

Below is my cutdown code (Note: a png named "dummy1024x1024.png" is required in the same folder as the binary):

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "dummy.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Dummy d(NULL);
    d.show();
    qDebug() << "App thread " <<  QThread::currentThreadId();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**dummy.h**

```
#ifndef DUMMY_H
#define DUMMY_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

#include "workerthread.h"

class Dummy : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Dummy(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~Dummy();
private:
    QVBoxLayout* m_layout;
    QPushButton* m_dummy[3];
    QPushButton* m_shootcalc;
    WorkerThread* m_work;
signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // DUMMY_H
```

**dummy.cpp**

```
#include "dummy.h"

Dummy::Dummy(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    m_work = new WorkerThread(this);
    m_work->start();

    m_shootcalc = new QPushButton("Calc!", this);
    connect(m_shootcalc, SIGNAL(clicked()), m_work, SLOT(expensiveCalc()), Qt::QueuedConnection);

    m_dummy[0] = new QPushButton("Dummy [0]", this);
    m_dummy[1] = new QPushButton("Dummy [1]", this);
    m_dummy[2] = new QPushButton("Dummy [2]", this);

    m_layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_shootcalc);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_dummy[0]);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_dummy[1]);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_dummy[2]);
    setLayout(m_layout);
}


Dummy::~Dummy()
{
    m_work->quit();
    m_work->wait();
    m_work->deleteLater();
    m_work = NULL;
}
```

**workerthread.h**

```
#ifndef WORKERTHREAD_H
#define WORKERTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QDebug>

class WorkerThread : public QThread
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WorkerThread(QObject *parent = 0);
protected:
    virtual void run();
signals:

public slots:
    void expensiveCalc();
};

#endif // WORKERTHREAD_H
```

**workerthread.cpp**

```
#include "workerthread.h"

WorkerThread::WorkerThread(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
}


void WorkerThread::run()
{
    qDebug() << "Thread start << " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    exec();
    qDebug() << "Thread stop << " << QThread::currentThreadId();
}

void WorkerThread::expensiveCalc()
{
    qDebug() << "start pixie loading.... " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    QPixmap* pixies[16384];
    for (int i=0; i<16384; ++i)
    {
        pixies[i] = new QPixmap("./dummy1024x1024.png");
        if (i>0)
            delete pixies[i-1];
        msleep(1);
    }
    delete pixies[16384-1];

    qDebug() << "loaded pixies " <<  QThread::currentThreadId();
    qDebug() << "";
    qDebug() << "";
    qDebug() << "";
    qDebug() << "";
}
```

Thanks for any help/tip/reply

Comment: there was an article in the german "Linux Magazin" a while back, about this problem. And there is some code available on github for workerthreads which work correctly with signals/slots. See here: http://github.com/picaschaf/Qt-Worker-Thread That might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for that information, I usually read the LinuxMagazine but I seem to have missed that.
I did the above code based on what the Qt Documentation and examples told me. Unfortunatly that QThread Documentation is one of the worst parts of the Qt Doc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper usage of `QThread` is a common problem among Qt users. This [blog post](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) at Qt Labs explains it nicely.

In short, you should **not** subclass `QThread` to contain code that you want to run in that thread. You should wrap your code up in a `QObject` subclass, instantiate it and use a `QObject::moveToThread` to move your object into the `QThread` context so that processing will occur in the context of that `QThread`. You can then have slots in your `QObject` subclass that can safely be connected to another thread but will run in the context you expect.

Some may argue that subclassing `QThread` should be fine if you can easily fit what you want to do inside the `run()` method and don't need much (or any) external interaction but even in this simple case I would favor a separate class for better encapsulation.

Comment: and to describe the actual problem: the QThread qobject itself lives in the main thread, not in the thread itself represents (!). The separation Arnold describes should make that clearer.

Comment: Thanks, yes, the QThread object "lives" in the main thread, so signals to it are processed in the main event loop which is what the OP is seeing.

Comment: there was an article in the german "Linux Magazin" a while back, about this problem. And there is some code available on github for workerthreads which work correctly with signals/slots. See here: http://github.com/picaschaf/Qt-Worker-Thread That might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @ArnoldSpence I believe you should subclass QThread, instead of creating seperate QObject subclass. If you call `moveToThread(this)` within the constructor of your derived QThread class, signals and slots will work as intended (executed in the slot's thread). Here is a more detailed description: http://engineer-dan.tumblr.com/post/36274332373/subclassing-qthread

Comment: @Daniel K. I'm aware of that technique. It looks like everything works normally when you do that but there are certain conditions under which you will have difficulty destroying them. Besides that, it is just bad object oriented design in that it violates the single responsibility principle.

Comment: @ArnoldSpence I agree. I've also recently looked at [this article](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) which supports what you're saying. However, in my current project I'm using it the way I proposed with no issues yet. This may change in the future of course.