# Qt: Worker thread that has slots and emitters on main thread

Tags: qt

Say I wanted to have a worker thread that has slots for signals emmited from the main application thread.

1. How would the "::run()" method of that worker thread look? obviously I need some kind of loop or the thread will terminate immediately. I want it to stick around so it can process the incoming slots. How would that loop look like? Something equivalent to sleep and pump messages? pump how?
2. Do I need to "MoveToThread()" all the objects that'll pass to the thread's slots so that the processing of the slot is done in the context of the worker thread?

Thank you.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911086/qthread-threaded-rly/3911440#3911440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some more digging.
The default implementation of QThread::run calls “exec” which is the message loop. So no extra work needed there. In the constructor of my QThread I add this:

```
this->start();
QObject::moveToThread(this);
```

As a result, my thread starts upon construction, and all signals outside the thread aimed at thread slots are executed in the context of my thread.

Comment: No! :) That is the misguided and and most repeated way to use QThreads. The short answer (contrary to QThread documentation). Don't subclass QThread. Subclass QObject to do the work you want and use moveToThread() to move it to an instance of QThread.

Comment: Interesting approach. What are the benefits of it? Also, is there a potential for catastrophe using the aforementioned method?

Comment: When I tried the method of subclassing QThread and moving it to its own thread in the constructor, I had a great deal of difficulty cleaning things up properly. In particular, you can't call deleteLater(). There were other issues with the order that things executed when signals and slots were introduced. It is a complete mess, even though it often seems to work fine.

Comment: For further assurance, this Qt Labs article hints that the word on QThread usage is spreading in the second screen shot :) http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/06/15/the-qt-documentation-has-made-it-into-devnet/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. I will make those changes in my code for QObject derived "worker" classes that are simply submitted to an instance of QThread.

Comment: See [this blog post](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) for a good discussion of this topic posted by the Qt folks.