# Is it possible in Qt to unit test (access) private methods?

Tags: unit-testing, qt, class, private-members, metaobject

I'm writing unit tests for my app, and now I've stumbled on a class in which I should test private methods. This could be result of poor design of particular class, but I must do it. Is there any way in Qt to call private methods, maybe using QMetaObject or something similar ?

For unit testing I am using QTestLib framework.

Comment: Just to comment that normally, only public methods are to be unittested. Private methods are an implementation detail: http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2008/11/21/do-not-test-private-methods/

Comment: kroonwijk: Thanks for the comment :) I know that, but this class is inheriting QThread, so only public methods are constructor and start(). And things that tread is doing are private methods. Now when I think about it, I should've done something different ... But there it is. My question still stands :)

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't subclass QThread  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911086/qthread-threaded-rly/3911440#3911440). Encapsulate your processing logic in a QObject subclass, create an instance of it and move it to an instance of QThread. This might help with your unit testing too.

Comment: Thank you ;) In future I'll use that methodology when using threads ... I think that I've read that I should subclass QThread in some book. Also, QT Documentation says "To create your own threads, subclass QThread and reimplement run()."

Comment: Yes, the documentation for Qt does suggest that and there is a very slow movement inside Trolltech to get it removed or at least updated :)

Comment: Here is a better answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186245/unit-testing-c-how-to-test-private-members

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper (read annoying) answer is that you should not be testing private methods, those are implementation details `;-)`.

OTOH -- have you thought about conditionally declaring them protected/private depending on whether you are in testing or no and then extending? I've used that to get me out of a similar pinch in the past.

```
#ifdef TESTING
// or maybe even public!
#define ACCESS protected
#else
#define ACCESS private
#endif

/* your class here */
class Foo {
ACCESS
    int fooeyness;
}

// or better yet, place this in a different file!
#ifdef TESTING
/*
    class which extends the tested class which has public accessors
*/
#endif
```

Comment: That is interesting way to resolve the problem :) I am still looking for another (qt specific) way to access private methods. But if I don't find it, I'll use this :) Thanks ;)

Comment: Or even dirtier: `#define private public` before you `#include" the header.

Comment: @larsm hahahah that scares me a little

Comment: @larsm ... That is *still* evil three years later. Just thought I would point that out. Seriously. It makes me cringe just thinking about that.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1, quick and easy: make the test class(es) a friend of the public one.

```
class Foo {
   // ...
private:
   friend class FooTest;
};
```

This way your `FooTest` class can access all members of the public class. However, this way you need to modify the original class every time you want to access private data from a different test, and you leak information about the tests in the public API, and you possibly open up for class naming conflicts (what if there's /another/ FooTest class around?), and so on.

---

Solution 2, aka properly done: don't put private methods in the public class, but make a private class with public methods.

```
class Foo {
    // 
private:
    friend class FooPrivate;
    FooPrivate *d;
};
```

`FooPrivate` gets declared in its own header, which may not be installed, or stay in a include-privates/ subdirectory, or whatever -- i.e. it stays out of the way for normal usage. The public class stays clean this way.

```
class FooPrivate {
public:
    // only public stuff in here;
    // and especially this:
    static FooPrivate *get(Foo *f) { return f->d; }
};
```

The test then includes the private header and calls `FooPrivate::get(fooObj)` to get the private class instance and then happily uses it.

Comment: Nice idea, but if `FooPrivate` isn't installed the program won't be able to compile. How about using Solution 1 but wrapping it in IFDEFs that are only enabled when tests are running?

Comment: Sure. But as I said, FooPrivate can be installed in some `include/private` subdirectory. Or, it can be installed only if one runs configure saying to enable tests...

Comment: I see what you mean now, but I'm not sure how that's an advantage over the very similar (and easier method) of wrapping `friend class TestFoo` in an `IFDEF` that is defined if project is configured to enable tests.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the "private members are implementation details" mentality, in my mind that roughly translates to "test only part of your code".

I can related to "units are units" argument, but why not try to cover as much of your code with tests as possible, even inside units? Aka. *giving your units a thorough rectal examination*.

And with this image in mind, one approach that I have been using frequently that is not mentioned in the other answers is to do the following:

1. Always declare members you want to test as `protected` in stead of `private` in your code.
2. Subclass your class in the testcode and simply make the selectors you need or simply write the test-code directly as members in that sub-class's implementation.

NOTE: You have to be careful with classes that rely on complex instantiation patterns to ensure that you construct them correctly (read: call the original class' constructor from the subclass ctor).

Answer (score 1):

I have found more convenient way to do this. First, all private methods should be private slots.
Then you create an instance of the class:

```
Foo a;
```

Then we can use QMetaObject::invokeMethod to call any slot that method has (public or private). So if we want to call method Test, we can do it like this:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&a, "Test", Qt::DirectConnection);
```

Also, we can have return value and send arguments ... Actually, everything is answered here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod

Comment: It is also possible to mark the private methods with `Q_INVOKABLE` instead of making them slots.

Comment: Doesn't this effectively make the method public?

Answer (score 0):

I've once read that Unit Test should test the class public interface, and not the protected/private stuff.

Your class should just behave right from outside. If implementation strategy changes, your Unit Test class is still the same.

Comment: But if you're testing a GUI, the private interface becomes "public" to the human using the GUI.